# Microsoft Access vba saving attachments to disk and storing the paths in the database

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a database that consists of about 3000 records which have attachments, my table's name is PRISONERS and I want the images stored under the "Attachments" field to be saved to a local directory and then have a field named images that store the paths to the corresponding images. NB: Some records store more than one attachments

I have a vba code that is supposed to perform this action but it only saves 5 pictures in the local directory which is C:\xampp\htdocs\nampol_suspects\uploads\photos and the Images field in the database has records for just the first picture(all 3000 records have the same path to the first picture only) Here's my code. I want the images field to store the path of the corresponding attachment which is an image in jpg format

```vb
Sub exportAttachments()
    Dim strPath, fName, fldName, sName(3) As String
    Dim rsPictures, rsDes As Variant
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim savedFile, i As Integer
    savedFile = 0

    ' Set the path where attachments will be saved
    strPath = "C:\xampp\htdocs\nampol_suspects\uploads\photos"

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [PRISONERS]")

    ' Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows
    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
        rs.MoveFirst ' Not required here, but still a good habit
        Do Until rs.EOF = True
            On Error Resume Next ' Ignore errors

            ' Instantiate the child record set.
            Set rsPictures = rs.Fields("Attachments").Value
            Set rsDes = rs.Fields("Name") ' Use to name the picture later

            ' If no attachment available, go to the next record
            If Len(rsPictures.Fields("FileName")) = 0 Then
                GoTo nextRS
            End If
            If rsPictures.RecordCount <> 0 Then
                rsPictures.MoveLast
                savedFile = rsPictures.RecordCount ' Set savedFile = total number of attachments
            End If
            rsPictures.MoveFirst ' Move to the first attachment file

            ' Loop through all attachments
            For i = 1 To savedFile ' Rename all files and save
                If Not rsPictures.EOF Then
                    ' Example with a constant file extension (e.g., .JPG)
                    fName = strPath & "\" & rsDes & i & ".JPG"
                    rsPictures.Fields("FileData").SaveToFile fName
                    sName(i) = fName ' Keep path in an array for later use
                    rsPictures.MoveNext
                End If
            Next i

            ' Insert image path and path into the database and edit
            rs.Edit

            ' Store the image path in the Images field
            rs.Fields("Images") = sName(1) ' Path

            ' Update the record
            rs.Update

    nextRS:
            rsPictures.Close ' Close attachment
            savedFile = 0 ' Reset for the next
            fName = 0 ' Reset

            ' Move to the next record.
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop

    Else
        MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."
    End If

    MsgBox "Attachments were exported!"

    rs.Close ' Close the db recordsets
    Set rs = Nothing ' Clean up
 End Sub
```

Comment: Your `i` resets for every record, if records have the same picture name, you want to add some distinguishing factor to those names, e.g. the PK of the record. Also, __NEVER__  do a  blanket `On Error Resume Next`. Only use this if you expect a specific error you want to ignore, and if you do, check if no other errors occurred and use `On Error Goto 0`  after the line where you expect the error. Currently, debugging is unnecessarily hard since errors may occur and we won't know about them

Comment: If any record has multiple images in Attachment field, need to save paths to a related dependent table (or use another multi-value field - a complication you really don't want). I don't see need to append record ID to file name if images are actually the same. Multiple records can use same image. If images are actually different, why would they have the same name? A single SQL INSERT INTO SELECT can save image paths to text field in table. It's image extraction that requires VBA looping code.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "it only saves 5 pictures". Are you saying 3000 records store image with same name? Is it actually the same image or different images with same name? How could the latter happen?

Comment: The `i` is iteration index for looping through Attachments recordset `rsPictures`. It should reset when moving to new parent record in `rs`. So not sure what Erik's point is with that comment.

Comment: Should be aware that VBA requires every variable to be explicitly declared or will default to Variant. In your first Dim line, only sName(3) is a String type, the others are all Variant. In the fourth, only i is Integer.

Comment: @June7 My point is quite simple: the OP indicates records may have identical filenames. Since `i` resets, identical filenames will lead to this code continuously overwriting the same pictures, which could explain this behaviour. A continuous `i` or other counter (or using the PK to make filenames unique) could avoid this.

Comment: Okay, so OP needs to clarify if this is actually same image stored to multiple records (horrors!) or  images are really different. It boggles my mind that different images would have been stored with same name. In either case, SQL can save image names to related table.